How to remove a border or box surrounding a text box from a Microsoft Access report?
After adding a "Country" label and textbox to the underlying query, and then to the report, the "Country" label has a box around it.  I cannot find the control to remove this box.
I've tried "special controls" from "properties" in design view, but cannot remove this box.
For this report:

the country textbox has a box around it for the report.
Here's the layout:

and design:

Copilot says:

In Microsoft Access, creating a border around a textbox in a report
isn’t as straightforward as it is in Excel. However, I’ll guide you
through a couple of workarounds to achieve a similar effect:
Simulating Borders with Line Segments:
    Access doesn’t offer the same level of control over borders as Excel does.
    To simulate a border, you can place one or more line segments around a textbox:
        For instance, use two horizontal line segments below a textbox to simulate a double bottom border.
    Here’s how:
        Add a textbox to your report.
        Place two horizontal lines (using line controls) below the textbox.
        Adjust their positions to create the desired border effect.
        You can extend the lines outside the textbox to achieve the look you want1.

Chiseled Special Effect:
    Another simple trick is to set the textbox’s Special Effect property to Chiseled:
        This will create a subtle border around the textbox.
    To do this:
        Select the textbox.
        In the Property Sheet, find the Special Effect property.
        Choose Chiseled from the dropdown menu.
    This won’t give you precise control over the border, but it’s a quick way to add some visual distinction1.

Remember that Access doesn’t provide the same fine-grained border
customization as Excel, so you’ll need to get creative with these
workarounds. Feel free to experiment and find the solution that best
suits your needs! 
For more detailed instructions, you can explore Microsoft’s official
support documentation on adding a text box control to a form or
report2. And if you’re a visual learner, check out YouTube tutorials
like this one for step-by-step guidance3. 

